# Verifying Function is called in Spray/Akka Router using Scala and Mockito

Tags: scala, routes, mockito, akka, spray

I'm trying to verify that a function in a router is being called but everytime I do, I get this error saying that there were no interactions with the mock object.

The function I would like to verify is the `doStuff` function so I'm mocking the `modelService` object.

This is my setup:

```
//Router
val foo(user: String, _: String, containerId: Long) => pathPrefix("foo"){
path("bar") {
    post {
      entity(as[someJson]) { report =>
        val actions = () => (for {
          msg <- eitherT((someActor? reportFunction(report.name, report.modelsTasks, user)).mapTo[\/[String, reportJson]])
          id <- eitherT(Future.successful(msg.id.toRightDisjunction("Cannot obtain id")))
          model <- eitherT(modelService.doStuff(user, id, containerId, report.asReportComponent()).
            map(_.right[String]))
        } yield model).run
        handleResult(actions())
      }
    }
  }
}

 \\Test
    "do some stuff when asked" in {
       when(modelService.doStuff(eqTo("unknown"), 
        any[String], eqTo(1L), any[reportComponent]))
        .thenReturn(Future.successful(expectedApp))
     Post("/foo/bar", someJson("Test")) ~>
      foo("unknown", "127.0.0.1", 1L) ~> check {
       verify( modelService, times(1) ).doStuff(eqTo("unknown"), any[String], eqTo(1L), any[reportComponent])
  }
}
```

But each time I run my test, I get something like this

```
Wanted but not invoked:
modelService.doStuff(
     "unknown",
     <any>,
     1,
     <any>
 );
 -> at com.this.test.spec.apply(ThisTestSpec.scala:112)
 Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you injecting the mock? could you post how you create your router class in the test?

Also, did you check that `msg <- eitherT` and `id <- eitherT` are returning a valid value? otherwise the `modelService` is never going to be called